# Python how to not print \r and \n

Tags: python

I have this code that runs a minecraft server from python and prints everything in the command line. However, at the end of every line it prints "\r\n" and I don't want it to, is there any way to get rid of it?

```
import subprocess

def run_command(command):
    p = subprocess.Popen(command,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return iter(p.stdout.readline, b'')

for output_line in run_command('java -Xmx2048M -Xms2048M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui'):
    print(output_line)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write to stdout directly:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("Hello world!")
sys.stdout.write(" I'm superman :D")
```

The above code should print on the same line

---

As requested, it seems like OP wants to print a long string with line breakers embedded, but don't want the line breakers to be effective.

Let's say I have a text file that has two lines

```
Hey line 1!
I'm line 2.
```

The following code will print two lines without line breaker, replacing line breakers with spaces:

```
txt = ''
with open('somename.txt', 'r') as f:
    txt = f.read().replace('\r\n', ' ')
    txt = txt.replace('\n\r', ' ')
    txt = txt.replace('\n', ' ')
    txt = txt.replace('\r', ' ')
print txt
```

That is, it will print

```
Hey line 1! I'm line 2.
```

You can also parse the lines, then print each line without line breakers:

```
for line in f:
     sys.stdout.write(line.strip() + ' ')
```

Hope this is what you want.

Comment: Don't forget `sys.stdout.flush()`

Comment: I don't want it to print on the same line, I want it to print multiple lines but the thing is, it's adding "\r\n" at the end of each line and I don't want that

Comment: @J.C. I think \r is recur and \n is newline. So what happens if you don't have neither of them at the end of a line?

Comment: It comes from the program itself. My code prints the server console (the java thing) to the command line (python script console). It's like printing a text file to the console, for example, and keeping the newlines in there. I just want a way for them not to be printed.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
print('Minecraft server', end="")
```

Or

```
print(output_line.rstrip())
```

Comment: python 2: print 'Minecraft server', # notice the comma in the end

Comment: I assume you mean print(output_line, end="") and that didn't work, the program didn't print anything

Comment: @EmmanuelMtali No, it didn't. It just didn't print anything as I said in the comment above. Could you add it to my code and post it? I might be doing it wrong